# Passing structure to function in C

Tags: c, structure, pass-by-value

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct point
{
int x;
int y;

};

void get(struct point p)
{
printf("Enter the x and y coordinates of your point: ");
scanf("%d %d",&p.x,&p.y);
}

void put(struct point p)
{
printf("(x,y)=(%d,%d)\n",p.x,p.y);
}




int main ()
{
struct point pt;
get(pt);
put(pt);
return 0;

}
```

I am trying to write a program to get the x and y coordinates from the user and them print them out to the screen. Once I enter the x and y coordinates and go out to print them out to the screen I get: (x,y)=(56,0). I am new to working with structures so any help would be good. Thank you.

Comment: You need to pass the struct by reference or pass a pointer to it. At the moment you are copying the whole struct when you send it to the get and put functions.

Answer (score 2):

You may also return the structure directly from get function, since this is a small structure.

```
struct point get()
{
struct point p;
printf("Enter the x and y coordinates of your point: ");
scanf("%d %d",&p.x,&p.y);
return p;
}

int main ()
{
put(get());
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void get(struct point *p)// get(&pt); call from main
{
    printf("Enter the x and y coordinates of your point: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&p->x,&p->y);
}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation of why his approach didn't work and yours does would make this a much more useful answer.

Comment: Since the structure is also passed to the function by value, So the function receives It is the copy. Would you like to return a structure that was updated for that, or you need to receive a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You had to use pointers, otherwise the point in the `get` function is a copy of the point in `main` function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;

} Point;

void get(Point *p)
{
    printf("Enter the x and y coordinates of your point: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&p->x,&p->y);
}

void put(Point *p)
{
    printf("(x,y)=(%d,%d)\n",p->x,p->y);
}


int main ()
{
    Point pt;
    get(&pt);
    put(&pt);
    return 0;
}
```